# PHP Insert Sort function performance

Tags: php, arrays, performance, sorting

I'm studying about sorting and I've made a insert sort function ([video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ROalU379l3U&feature=mfu_in_order&list=UL)):

```
<?php
set_time_limit(null);

function insertSort(array &$array)
{
    $array_size = count($array);
    $tmp = null;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $array_size; $i++)
    {
        $j = $i + 1;
        if ($j == $array_size)
        {
            break;
        }
        while ($array[$j] < $array[$i])
        {
            $tmp = $array[$i];
            $array[$i] = $array[$j];
            $array[$j] = $tmp;

            if ($i > 0)
            {
                $i--;
            }
            $j--;
        }
    }
}

$array = range(0, 100);
shuffle($array);//array(3, 0, 1, 8, 7, 2, 5, 4, 9, 6);

$time_start = microtime(true);
insertSort($array);
$time_end = microtime(true);
echo ($time_end - $time_start);
?>
```

I've got the following results with microtime:

```
10000 integers - 69.174551010132
5000 integers - 16.151810884476
1000 integers - 0.7065761089325
500 integers - 0.18473505973816
100 integers - 0.0077528953552246
```

How can I improve the performance of my insert sort function?
Thank you.

Comment: The for loop guarantees the order in which the array is iterated. foreach *may* return the elements in non-sequential order.

Comment: foreach has a bad performance: http://www.phpbench.com/. Thank you.

Comment: Do you really have an *actual* performance problem? A practical one? Note that phpbench deals in microseconds - a *millionth* of a second. Most comparisons shown there will have no real world impact on code whatsoever. Every database request you make will take thousands of times longer.

Comment: Actually no. I'm just studying. Thank you.

Comment: You would probably be better off using mysql.

Comment: Does PHP actually matter in this case then or are you trying to find a language agnostic way to make this happen efficiently?

Comment: Actually I did it in PHP because I'm a PHP programmer. As I said before, i'm just studying. Thank you!

Comment: Okay, insertion sort has a worst case of complexity n^2... are you looking for an algorithm that has a better worst case complexity?

Answer (score 3):

An insertion sort isn't a very efficient algorithm for large numbers of items.

The take away here is there is no amount of optimization you can do to make a significant difference if the algorithm itself is slow.

Write a your sort using the mergesort or quicksort alogrithm and your sort times on will be reduced significantly.

Comment: @thom If you want to study sorting, you want to cover all your bases!

Answer (score 1):

```
function insertionSort($array){
    $length = count($array);

    for($j=1;$j<$length;$j++){
        $key = $array[$j];
        $i=$j-1;
        while($i>=0 && $array[$i]>$key){
            $array[$i+1]=$array[$i];
            $array[$i]=$key;
            $i--;
        }
    }
    return $array;
}
```

use this function 
in my machine: for 10000 
time taken by this is: 7.4051690101624 and
above mention function is: 21.813783884048